# Deploy CakePHP to a subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, shared-hosting

I have created a CakePHP 2 app, and now I'm trying to deploy it to a production web server.

My app uses the default folder structure (app/lib/plugins/vendors), default htaccess, default routing, nothing special.

I've been developing locally as if the app were in the root folder of the site (e.g. http://mycakeapp.localhost/ takes me to the site). But I'm deploying to a site (shared hosting) where that will not be the case (e.g. http://www.somedomain.com/mycakeapp).

It doesn't work (I didn't really expect it to), so I assumed I had to tweak one or more htaccess files. I tried modifying the root .htaccess [as suggested in this post](http://mamun.info/2010/09/08/cakephp-in-a-subdirectory/), but that only partially worked (the link to the CSS didn't work, for instance):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^mycakeapp$  mycakeapp/app/webroot/  [L]
RewriteRule  ^mycakeapp/(.*)$  mycakeapp/app/webroot/$1  [L]
</IfModule>
```

So what should I do to all the htaccess files to make this CakePHP site work in a subfolder?

### UPDATE:

There's an .htaccess file in the root of the site, I've pasted its contents below. Is something in there screwing it up?

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somedomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.somedomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^secure/$ https://www.somedomain.com/secure [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^about\.html$ /contact.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^contact\.html$ /contact.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^download\.html$ /signup.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /index.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^privacy\.html$ /policies.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^website\.html$ /business-websites.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^return\.html$ /policies.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Normally that should work out of the box (it always did for me), the top most `.htaccess` file (the one that will be located directly in your subfolder) that comes with the CakePHP package should do the job, it passes the request to the `app/webroot` directory where it will be processed just as if `app/webroot` would be the document root. Maybe you should exaplain what exactly isn't working, ie what happens, and what should happen instead?

Comment: Sure, what I get is a 400 error (Bad Request, Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.) If I make changes like I did above, then it seems to work okay, but the CSS/JS isn't loaded.

Comment: Some more information: http://mydomain.com/ezr4/ (with trailing slash) gives me a 404, without trailing slash I get that 400. Both are custom error pages, not default browser error pages.

Comment: I can't see what might cause a `400`, but the file is cleary lacking some redirecting to `app/webroot`, which makes the `404` inevitable. Have you tried using the default `.htaccess` file that comes with Cake, it should look similar to your modification, just without your custom subfolder name? The subfolder name shouldn't be neccessary, in fact I think that this would cause the rules not to match.

Answer (score 0):

This post is a little old, but found it when doing reconaissance for my first CakePHP app deployment to a subfolder. The following .htaccess line can modify the root folder (for):

```
RewriteBase /subdir/
```

Sometimes Apache requires additional permissions or options in the httpd.conf or virtual hosts configuration file, similar to below:

```
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html/site_folder>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml
    </Directory>
```